# video.supersample does not exist

Tags: python, video, moviepy

Im writing a program to slow and supersample a video and I've gotten the video to slow down, but when I try to use the same method to supersample it

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.fx.all import *

video = VideoFileClip("People - 6387.mp4")

result = video.speedx(0.5)

blurred = result.supersample()

result.write_videofile("slowedvideo.mp4")
```

I expected a slowed and blurred video to be written into the folder, but instead, I get an error saying

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/21kingai/OneDrive - De Smet Jesuit High School/Documents/PythonF/Movietest.py", line 8, in <module>
    blurred = result.supersample()
AttributeError: 'VideoFileClip' object has no attribute 'supersample'
```

Comment: where did you found this example ? Did you check in documentation if it has `supersample` ? You could also check `print( dir(result) )` to see all methods available for this object.

Comment: documentation [supersample](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.supersample.html?highlight=sample#moviepy.video.fx.all.supersample) - it seems `supersample(result, ..., ...)`

Comment: @furas thank you so much, that worked, it seemed the same as speedx in the documentation, but I never saw the clip parameter. Thank you so much